# Can't transfer an image element from one file to another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to transfer an image element, which is hosted on the cloud, from one file to another but it's not working.

I tried to insert the image in the HTML when it loads but it's telling me that the image variable is null.

**MY FIRST HTML FILE(source file)**

```
 <div class="card">
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mo1/image/upload/v1564584621/kobe_lq48jt.jpg"  id="mentorPicOne" alt="">
                <strong><p>Kobe Bryant </p></strong>
                <div class="mentor-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_id"> 
                        <label for="check_id"></label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>Bio: </strong> A 44-year old husband and father of 2.</li><br>
                        <li><strong>Occupation: </strong> Retired professional basketball player</li><br>
                        <li><strong>Expertise: </strong> 5 years</li><br>
                        <button class="reach-btn"  onclick="openPage()"> Reach Out</button>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
```

**MY SECOND HTML FILE (destination file)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/accusoft.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/my_mentor.css">
    <title>Free Mentors | My Mentor </title>
</head>

<body onload="onload()">
    <div class="main-container">

        <header class="header">
            <a class="logo" href="/">

                <span id="logo-icon">
                    <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
                </span>
                <h3>Free<span id="free-mentors">Mentors</span></h3>
            </a>

            <div class="register-buttons">
                <a href="/"><button class="button">Back</button></a>
                <a href="/"><button class="button" id="admin-dash">Log Out</button></a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <h2>My Mentor</h2>
        <main class="content-container">
            <div class="selected-mentor">

            </div>
        </main>

        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Free Mentors 2019</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="../js/my_mentor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**JavaScript File (my_mentor.js)**

```
const mentorPicOne = document.getElementById('mentorPicOne'); ;
const selectedMentor = document.querySelector('.selected-mentor')


console.log('The selected', mentorPicOne)


openPage = async ()=>{
    window.location.assign('./my_mentor.html'); 
}

function onload(){  
    selectedMentor.innerHTML = mentorPicOne;

}
```

I want to be able to click the **React Out** button, hence executing the openPage function, and then go the *my_mentor* page having the image inside of it.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by transferring from one file to other? its just a url, it can be placed in both pages. the image is not really on the page, its requesting it from your url and showing it in your html.

Comment: Thanks, @Ariel. You helped me see do it in a different way and it worked.

Comment: Hi @Ariel, I upvoted your answer but since I don't have 50 reputations required to affect the voting you can't see it. Basically, I referenced image's external source in the new file. 

Thanks.